# $("#" + id).length returns 0 but the element exists(solved, reason: id cannot includes meta-characters )

Tags: jquery, html

What is the difference between `document.getElementById(id)` and `$("#"+id).length`?

I have a div width with id where `document.getElementById(id)` returns true while `$("#" + id).length` returns `0`. Why is this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.getElementById(go_to_comment)){
        alert("the element exists");
    }

    var aaa = $('#' + go_to_comment);
    if (aaa.length == 0) {
        alert("the element does not exist");
    }
});
```

Why are both `alert` statements are executed? If `document.getElementById(go_to_comment)` is true, then `aaa.length` should not be 0!

Comment: There is no difference. I'm unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/mfuyxgoL/1/. Please add a working example of the problem.

Comment: Doesn't aaa.length != 0 mean that the element exists?

Comment: Yes, but I'm just doing that to get the same result from both methods. I've just updated the fiddle to show all possible outcomes: https://jsfiddle.net/mfuyxgoL/2/. Either way, your code should be working.

Comment: go_to_comment is sent by json, does it matter?

Comment: So long as the variable has a value (which it appears that it does given that it's working with `getElementById`) then it should make no difference.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan a posssible way to reproduce the issue. Put a space after the id. check this https://jsfiddle.net/mfuyxgoL/4/

Comment: go_to_comment is 12016-02-16%2017:43:47 which includes space(%20). Does it matter?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi very good point

Comment: @KeroroChan that is your problem; the value there has several characters (the space, `:` and `%`) which are illegal in a selector and you need to escape them.

Comment: Are there method to escape?

Comment: Or should I use 12016021617:43:47?

Comment: @KeroroChan  check this link https://jsfiddle.net/praveentpt/kqm9osow/24/

Comment: [jQuery: Category: Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) `[...]To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.[...]`

Comment: Thank you a lots. Finally, I rename the id without meta-characters eg. 1_2016-02-16_17_43_47

Answer (score 0):

please find the jsfiddle link below for your answer. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praveentpt/mfuyxgoL/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var go_to_comment="comment";
console.log(document.getElementById(go_to_comment))
if (document.getElementById(go_to_comment)){
    alert("the element exists");
}

var aaa = $('#' + go_to_comment + "");
if (aaa.length == 0) {
    alert("the element does not exist");
}
});
```